# Xcode - Non matching & non expired provisioning profiles found - free dev account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

**Non matching & non expired provisioning profiles found**

I've been working over this issue and came across SO threads and I have not succeeded till now.
 First off all, I'm using a free developer account so I am not able to login to the developer account portal and manage certificates and profiles.

I did not face any problem till now, after that I upgraded to Xcode 7.3.1
 I am able to run the app on simulator but not on a real device

i *am* able to create a new project and run it on a real device, this only affects projects that I had created prior to upgrade

After that:
 - Checked that certificates were valid under keychain access

- deleted account from Xcode > preferences > accounts > appleIds
- navigated to appleIds > view details : ensured that provisioning profiles were downloaded and non expired
- deleted existing provisioning profiles from provisioned profiles directory and then created them again
- cleared all profiles, deleted the account, recreated the account, triggered product > profile
- verified that my iOS development cert is valid and did not create  in Xcode
- restarted Xcode at every stage of this process, as per multiple threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all of the posts I've seen, I'm sure this will help someone out there.

Go to project build settings > code signing > code signing identity
check that the provisioning profile you've made is set.

after I did this, I was still receiving an error. this time for entitlements. I browsed to project > capabilities > health kit (where the issue was) and found a 'fix issue' button. This solved the second half of the problem. good luck out there